# Java JOGL2 and Mouse Listeners

Tags: opengl, jogl

I've been using JOGL2 with java and I'm really having an issue with mouse event listeners.  I can get the mouse listener to update its x and y position if I use public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e), but it will not redraw on the public void display(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable)

Here's how my code works:
This is my main method where the window and the listeners are constructed

```
 import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
 import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

 import javax.media.opengl.GL2;
 import javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilities;
 import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;
 import javax.media.opengl.GLProfile;
 import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;

 import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;

 public class HelloWorld 
 {
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
      // setup OpenGL Version 2
    GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
    GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(profile);
    Renderer render = new Renderer();

    // The canvas is the widget that's drawn in the JFrame
    GLCanvas glcanvas = new GLCanvas(capabilities);
    glcanvas.addGLEventListener(render);
    glcanvas.addMouseListener(render);
    glcanvas.addMouseMotionListener(render);
    glcanvas.setSize( 800, 600 );

      JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Graphics Demo" );

      frame.getContentPane().add( glcanvas);

     // shutdown the program on windows close event
     frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() 
     {
          public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev) {
            System.exit(0);
         }
     });

    frame.setSize( frame.getContentPane().getPreferredSize() );
    frame.setVisible( true );
   }
 }
```

Here is my OpenGL rendering class, it renders just ONE frame and it will not re-render unless I adjust the window size for some reason.  If I decide to use a mouse listener, it will update the values but it will not update the rendering.  Why is this?

```
 import java.io.*;
 import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
 import javax.media.opengl.GL2;
 import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
 import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;
 import javax.media.opengl.glu.GLU;
 import java.awt.Dimension;
 import java.awt.Frame;
 import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
 import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
 import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
 import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
 import javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilities;
 import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;
 import javax.media.opengl.GLProfile;
 import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
 import com.jogamp.opengl.util.FPSAnimator;

 import javax.media.opengl.glu.GLUquadric;

 import java.awt.Graphics2D;
 import java.awt.color.ColorSpace; 
 import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
 import java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel;
 import java.awt.image.DataBuffer;
 import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
 import java.awt.image.Raster;
 import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
 import java.awt.event.*;

 class Renderer implements GLEventListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
 {

    private GLU glu = new GLU();
    float x = 1;
    float y = 1;
    float z = 1;

    private GLUquadric quadric;
    GLCanvas canvas;

public void init(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable) 
{
    System.out.println("INIT CALLED");
}

public void display(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable) 
{

    final GL2 gl = gLDrawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    /*MODELS LOADED HERE*/
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, -9.0f, -150.0f); //-1.5f 0.0f -6.0f
    gl.glRotatef(15f+x, 45f+x, 0f+y,0f); //15 45 0 0 

    OBJloader playingField = new OBJloader("PlayingField.obj", "Crema_Timber.jpg");
    OBJloader coin = new OBJloader("coin.obj","early_shilling.jpg");
    OBJloader tower = new OBJloader("Tower1.obj","stone.jpg");
    OBJloader tower2 = new OBJloader("Tower2.obj","stone.jpg");

    /* 3D RENDERING COMPUTED HERE */
    playingField.DrawModel(gl);
    coin.DrawModel(gl);     
    tower.DrawModel(gl);
    tower2.DrawModel(gl);

 }




 public void displayChanged(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable, boolean modeChanged, boolean deviceChanged) 
{
    System.out.println("displayChanged called");
}



public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) 
{
    System.out.println("reshape() called: x = "+x+", y = "+y+", width = "+width+", height = "+height);
     final GL2 gl = gLDrawable.getGL().getGL2();

     if (height <= 0)
     {
        height = 1;
     }

    final float h = (float) width / (float) height;

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    glu.gluPerspective(45.0f, h, 1.0, 200.0);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
}


 public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable arg0) 
 {
System.out.println("dispose() called");
 }



 @Override
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) 
 {  
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     System.out.println("Mouse Clicked");
 }


 @Override
 public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) 
 {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     System.out.println("Mouse Entered Frame");
 }


 @Override
 public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) 
 {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     System.out.println("Mouse Exited Frame");
 }


 @Override
 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) 
 {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     System.out.println("Mouse is pressed.");
 }


 @Override
 public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) 
 {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
System.out.println("Mouse has been released");
 }

 //HERE IS THE PROBLEM, THE DISPLAY WILL NOT UPDATE THIS INPUT
 @Override
 public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
 {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
System.out.println("Mouse is being dragged");
x = e.getX();
y = e.getY();

System.out.println("x = "+x);
System.out.println("y = "+y);   
 }


 @Override
 public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) 
 {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
System.out.println("Mouse has moved.");
 }

 }
```

You may notice that there are certain functions that say:
OBJloader SOMETHING = new OBJloader("SOMETHING.obj", "SOMETHING.jpg");

I have another class that loads OBJ files and textures them, its drawing function is simple, it just reads in the data in arrays and calls glDrawArrays (Also note all the imports, its actually to be used later).

The last thing I need to do with this is figure out a way to get this mouse to update

Comment: use the animator class to update.(maybe work)

Answer (score 0):

in you HelloWorld class you should start an animator:

```
FPSAnimator animator = new FPSAnimator(canvas, 60);
animator.start();
```